# What happens if one of the two accused flees the country?

Tags: criminal-law, criminal-procedure

Context: I'm watching a series on Netflix called **Brooklyn Nine-nine**, a comedy series. No spoilers please. I'm fond of law stuff and I don't know much about laws in the US, I live somewhere in Asia, by the way.

I'm in the episode wherein the two good cops are accused of robbing a bank, they were caught red-handed, and the evidences planned against them were just too strong. So one of the two accused cop apparently gave up and is about to flee the country, go to Argentina specifically.

Questions:

What happens if that cop goes to other country? Will they be found guilty automatically? If not, what if the lone cop wins the case? Can the other cop who fled go back to the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conviction for a crime is never automatic, there must be a trial. The remaining accused can be tried and convicted or acquitted based on whatever evidence there is. If you flee the US, you *can* return (these guys are presumed to be US citizens): you may or may not (probably will) be prosecuted upon your return. Or, the accused could be [extradited from Argentina](https://www.congress.gov/105/cdoc/tdoc18/CDOC-105tdoc18.pdf). It's not just TV, it's often-surreal comedy.

Comment: It'd be worth adding that the criminal prosecution would continue as to the remaining defendant, even if the other defendant had fled.

Comment: If there are two defendants, it may be possible that we can prove that between them they committed the crime, but we have a hard time proving who is more responsible. The defendant who stayed will likely try to put all the blame on the one who ran, and there is nobody in court to contradict them.